# how to animate new added items to list in wpf's listview

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a dynamic listview `lstDummies` which contain a dummy UserController `dummyItem` :

```
dummyItem item;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    item = new dummyItem ();
    lstDummies.Items.Add(item);

}
```

here is dummyItem XAML :

```
<UserControl x:Class="Kiosk.control.dummyItem"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         x:Name="dummyItem">
<Grid Background="BurlyWood">
    <TextBox Text="hello world!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
</Grid>

</UserControl>
```

here is my XAML:

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lstDummies">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5">
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel >
            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                <UniformGrid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Columns="17"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
 </ListView>
```

now i want fade effect when the new item is added to lstDummies.

Comment: @dymanoid the problem is fade animation didn't work. I want the Newly added items are displayed with fading effect

Comment: You have defined the style in resources but i don't see it being used. Move the style to `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`

Comment: @Aakanksha ItemContainerStyle didn't recognized

Comment: What does that mean? You are not able to add ItemContainerStyle?

Comment: @Aakanksha yes, where should I add?

Comment: Instead of ListView.Resources make it ListView.ItemContainerStyle

Comment: I took your code and markup and tried it. I added a button to control adding the items and used a textblock instead of whatever your usercontrol is. That worked ok for me. The  animation is kind of quick and of course they'll all appear at once since adding objects in a tight loop is quick AND will block the UI from doing anything since it's on the UI thread. Maybe this is not what you're expecting, but it kind of works.  Maybe you have a problem in your usercontrol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me, i.e. the `Opacity` is set to `0` and then animated once the `ListViewItem` has been loaded:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstDummies">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel >
        <ItemsPanelTemplate >
            <UniformGrid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Columns="17"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Green" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If you want the items to fade in one by one, you should introduce a delay between the calls to `Add`:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        lstDummies.Items.Add(new dummyItem());
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure ? didn't work for me. the items added with delay without fade effect

Comment: @PouyaAk: Did you try my example? The `Rectangles` should fade in. Try to increase the duration of the animation to see it clearer.

Comment: I exactly copy your code, unfortunately, didn't work, the rectangles are added without fading. I also increase the duration of the animation and delay time but NO